# Java socket programming writebytes to readline

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to get a java server and client communicating. For streaming data to the server I have this code:

```
  Socket ClientSocket = null;
ClientSocket = new Socket(IPAddress, portInt); 
DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(ClientSocket.getOutputStream());

    outToClient.writeBytes(command);
    outToClient.flush();
```

And for the server I have:

```
        ServerSocket mysocket = new ServerSocket(8081);
        Socket connectionsocket = mysocket.accept();

        BufferedReader inFromClient =
           new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionsocket.getInputStream()));

        DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionsocket.getOutputStream());

        //program hangs here, client not sending

        GetRequest = inFromClient.readLine();
        System.out.println("Received: " + GetRequest);
```

These are only short portions of the overall code, I have found that the program hangs on the server side when the readLine(); is reached. I am trying to send data with writeBytes(command); where command is a string. Any suggestions? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> writebytes to readline

Stop right there. If you're using `readLine()` you're using `BufferedReader`, which is a `Reader`, which means you should be using a `Writer` to talk to it, which means you should be using a `BufferedWriter`, and as you're reading lines you must write lines, which means writing a line terminator (which you aren't presently doing), which means you should use `BufferedWriter.newline()`.

Or `PrintWriter.println(),` but don't forget to check for errors, as it swallows exceptions.

Answer (score -1):

Don't directly use `readLine`

Instead try this

```
If( inFromClient.ready()){
   // read string here.
}
```

It might be possible that buffer is not ready and you are trying to read. So it can create problem.

Comment: Okay thanks this shows me that my input stream is not ready. I run an if statement as such it will print, so maybe I could delay the input stream? `if(!inFromClient.ready()){System.out.println("inFromClient not ready");}`

Comment: The only 'problem' it can create is a block in `readLine()`. This is poor advice in general, and pointless in this case.